# Installing ubuntu (i dont have free space)

Tags: dual-boot

[image]

I'm trying to install Ubuntu. and i don't have "install Ubuntu alongside windows10" option during installation.
i shrunk a 100Gb volume. and instead of appearing "free space" in installing,
there is "unused space". and i can't do anything with that.

Comment: What type of partition table do you have?   If it's MBR/legacy then only 4 primary partitions are allowed (and unused space can only be used to expand existing partitions, not create new partitions).  What type is your partition table? and how many primary partitions are already used?

Comment: yes, i have 4 primary partitions. how can change it? just reinstall windows?

Comment: If a primary partition is changed (usually erased & re-created) to an extended partition; you can create a number of partitions within the extended partition and they only count as one primary partition (the extended partition).  Windows by default can only achieve this by deleting & re-creating a blank 'extended' partition. How this is best achieved will depend on what you have in your partitions, what you need to keep and how you can reduce what you have down to three, leaving one for your Ubuntu install (or use four and leave space within an extended partition that Ubuntu can use)

Comment: To expand on the excellent advice of guiverc, look in D: and E: (since G:  is labeled as a System partition, let's leave it alone for now). If you decide to move files from D: to E: then make a folder in E: named \Old-D and move files from D into E:\Old-D . When you've moved everything out of D: (either to E:\Old-D or someplace else), then you can delete the D: partition in Disk Manager, create a new Extended partition. You can then make a Logical partition D: and move those files back in. Once that's done, install Ubuntu with the Alongside option will work.